# Multiple-entry Schengen visa, possible issues on Estonian border control?

Tags: visas, schengen, borders, estonia, ukrainian-citizens

I'm granted one year multiple-entry Schengen business visa, which I got in Swedish embassy in Kiev, Ukraine.
I've already visited Sweden and stayed there for about 4 weeks.

I'm planning to visit Estonia soon for tourism purposes and would like to know if it is okay to travel as a tourist with business visa?

Comment: You are Ukrainian citizen, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  
Perhaps, this may be relevant: I've already had tourist and business Schengen visas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have Schengen Visa Type (C), which is valid for short stay for:

- Tourist
- Business

You can use your visa as a tourist, there are no separate Schengen visas for business and tourists.

Comment: Most likely you are right, this is type C visa. I'll check it when I'll get home.

Comment: Checked a minute ago, this is type C visa :).

Comment: @Volodymyr So you can go as a tourist :) enjoy it :)